# ASP.Net Core Unable to restore .Net Framework 4.6.1 reference

Tags: asp.net-core

I am new to ASP.Net core project. One of my friend has shared me his sample application with me to make improvements.

Once I downloaded the project I am not able to restore the .Net framework 4.6.1 reference in the ASP.Net Core Project.

Any suggestion how to restore it ?

Comment: Should we install the ASP.Net Core or vs2015 by default is shipped with it ?

Comment: http://microsoft.com/net/core#windows ...

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem since not all my references was not successfully restored.

In order to restore it, I found that nuget was not able to restore all the files.

Finally after search, I found nuget restore is not reliable in Core. Hence "dotnet restore" in Package manager console I was able to solve the problem.